# Getting issue when click on product to product details page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-page

**Version:**  Magento 2.2.0

**Website URL:** https://aat-testing.com/sinus-care.html

**Theme :** Magento default theme luma

when you click on the website URL you will see a product, the problem is that when I am clicking on the product for view in details page I am facing errors.

**The Error is:**

[image]

There is something related to `price.phtml` file finalpricebox_0
I have replaced files but still error showing, can anyone suggest me in right way what is the problem?  please many thanks in advance. I am new in Magento 2.

here is `price.phtml` i have found in the module :

```
<div class="price-box range second price-final_price" data-role="priceBox" data-product-id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductId() ?>">
    <span class="product-price">
        <span class="price-container price-final_price">
            <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
                <span class="price-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayLabel(); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
                data-price-amount=""
                data-price-type="finalPrice1"
                class="price-wrapper">
                <span class="price"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayValue();?></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Search with `price.phtml` in your `SFC_Natlallergy` and check if you find something

Comment: Please try to remove generated folder and check.

Comment: @Keyur thanks for help can you tell me the path of SFC_Natlallergy folder actually I am using multistore so in the store which is using default Magento luma theme I am not finding the SFC_Natlallergy, please little guide me more i can do this.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. sir can you tell me where it is ?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. in root i have found the folder i have rename it but its still showing error

Comment: you can find it app>code>`SFC `directory @R.K.Bhardwaj

Comment: @KeyurShah Sir I have found one price.phtml but don't know what to do there any suggestion please

Comment: Post your `XML` file(which you found the via searching) and `price.phtml` file location and update the question @R.K.Bhardwaj

Comment: @KeyurShah  Thankyou so much i have solve the problem into the finalpricebox.php to comment  the code :   protected function _beforeToHtml() {
  if($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view')
   $this->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/view/price.phtml');
  return parent::_beforeToHtml();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment you need to check in `app > code > SFC` directory and search with `price.phtml` and confirm the file path is exist in your module or not.